# JSON column expand databricks sql

Tags: sql, json, azure-databricks

I have the JSON column which and would like to expand it using databricks sql (no python).

column name is cdi_sentemailstatisticsdata, and each json value has its corresponding id too and sample data:

```
{"list":[{"Count":91,"EmailClient":"Other","Platform":"Desktop"},{"Count":20,"EmailClient":"Hotmail","Platform":"Desktop"},{"Count":5,"EmailClient":"Chrome Mobile","Platform":"Desktop"},{"Count":2,"EmailClient":"Opera","Platform":"Desktop"},{"Count":35,"EmailClient":"Chrome","Platform":"Desktop"},{"Count":21,"EmailClient":"Outlook","Platform":"Desktop"},{"Count":26,"EmailClient":"Gmail","Platform":"Desktop"},{"Count":1,"EmailClient":"Safari","Platform":"Desktop"},{"Count":1,"EmailClient":"Icloud","Platform":"Desktop"},{"Count":1,"EmailClient":"Thunderbird","Platform":"Desktop"},{"Count":1,"EmailClient":"Outlook.com","Platform":"Desktop"},{"Count":16,"EmailClient":"Chrome Mobile","Platform":"Mobile"},{"Count":22,"EmailClient":"Mobile Safari","Platform":"Mobile"},{"Count":8,"EmailClient":"Hotmail","Platform":"Mobile"},{"Count":6,"EmailClient":"Yahoo","Platform":"Mobile"},{"Count":4,"EmailClient":"Gmail","Platform":"Mobile"},{"Count":1,"EmailClient":"Chrome","Platform":"Mobile"}],"lastUpdate":"2020-11-11T13:31:14.3587369+00:00"}
```

Desired output should look like this:

[image]

Tried something like this but did not work:

```
SELECT
  json_element.Count AS Count,
  json_element.EmailClient AS EmailClient,
  json_element.Platform AS Platform
FROM
  cdi_sentemailstatisticsdata
LATERAL VIEW
  explode(from_json(json_column.list, 'array<struct<Count:int,EmailClient:string,Platform:string>>')) AS json_element;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below SQL query.

```
SELECT
    json_element.Count  AS  Count,
    json_element.EmailClient AS EmailClient,
     json_element.Platform AS Platform
FROM
(
SELECT cdi_sentemailstatisticsdata as json_column from your_table_name
) t
LATERAL  VIEW
explode(from_json(json_column, 'struct<list:array<struct<Count:int,EmailClient:string,Platform:string>>,lastUpdate:string>').list) AS json_element;
```

Output:

[image]